# XNA, how to draw all DrawableGameObjects?

Tags: c#, xna

I remember a while back seeing some way to draw and update all drawablegameobjects. I think it was a foreach loop such as

```
      foreach(DrawableGameComponent dgc in Game.Components)
```

Can someone please tell me the correct way to do this or if they know a tutorial for it?

Thanks!

Comment: As long as you have base.Update();  & base.Draw();  in your game's I update and draw methods, all game components will be updated and drawn automatically.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it this way:

```
foreach(var dgc in Game.Components.OfType<DrawableGameComponent>()
                                  .OrderBy(x => x.DrawOrder))
{

}
```

Comment: Actually the best answer here in my opinion. I would add a `.Where(x => x.Visible)` to the Linq query.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct, you can simply loop over each item in the Components array and call it's draw method, there are a few things that you should take in to account though, the following code should work for you.

You might not need to order by DrawOrder if it doesn't matter to you and you probably shouldn't do it with linq anyway since it's pretty slow but here ya go.

```
foreach (var component in Components.OrderBy(x => ((IDrawable)x).DrawOrder))
  if (component is IDrawable)
  {
     IDrawable drawableComponent = (IDrawable)component;
     if (drawableComponent.Visible)
        drawableComponent.Draw(gameTime);
  }
```

Comment: This code will crash if you have non visual game components added to your components. A regular `GameComponent` or `IGameComponent` cannot be cast to the `IDrawable` interface to query the draw order. You have to check the type before you do.

Answer (score 0):

Since the objects may extend the DrawableGameObject you can always add it to your game components:

```
class MyGame: Game
{
     //...Your code
     override public Load()
     {
           //... YOURCODE  
           Components.Add(myDrawableObj);
     }
 }
```

You'll notice that they will start drawing themselves :)